# Angular, добавить массив объектов в объект, находящийся в массиве объектов

Tags: массивы, typescript, angular, объекты

Есть массив с объектами(clients), которые содержат массив объектов(orders)

```
clients: client[] = [
{
  name: 'Иванов',
  phone: '+7999999',
  car: {
    name: 'Mitsubishi', vin: 'jmbsncs3a5u012840', mileAge: 50000, number: '001',
    },
  orders: [
    {date: '13-06-2022', mileAge: 50000, jobs: [{name: 'Диагностика', price: 0}]},
    {date: '10-06-2022', mileAge: 50000, jobs: [{name: 'замена топливного насоса', price: 500},{
        name: 'диагностика ходовой части', price: 500}]}]
},
{
  name: 'Петров',
  phone: '+7999999',
  car: {
    name: 'bmw', vin: 'jmbsncs3a5u012840', mileAge: 50000, number: '001',
  },
  orders: [
    {date: '13-06-2022', mileAge: 50000, jobs: [{name: 'Диагностика', price: 0}]},
    {date: '10-06-2022', mileAge: 50000, jobs: [{name: 'замена топливного насоса', price: 500},{
        name: 'диагностика ходовой части', price: 500}]}]
},]
```

Нужно получить доступ к массиву orders и добавить в него новый объект.

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Не понимаю какой метод использовать, учусь работать с angular

Comment: Не знаете про метод `push()`?

Comment: Знаю, вопрос в том, что-бы найти объект по имени или телефону и у его массива orders вызвать push.

Comment: Перебирайте в цикле массив `client`, пока не найдете подходящий элемент. Или используйте метод `find()`, что, в принципе, одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, получилась такая конструкция:
 this.clientsService.clients.find(client => client.name == this.form.value.searchClient).orders.push()

Comment: Ответьте сами на свой вопрос и отметьте как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.clientsService.clients.find(client => client.name == this.form.value.searchClient).orders.push()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]